# Посчитать количество единиц в числе

Tags: c++, c, битовые-операции

Вопрос предельно прост: надо посчитать количество единиц в двоичном представлении числа за О(1). Линии и логарифмы даже не предлагайте. Интересует только О(1).

Comment: В подобных вопросах критической деталью является определение элементарных операций, в терминах которых выражается время выполнения. В общем случае для решения данной задачи нужно O(log N) времени. O(1) недостаточно. O(1) может получится только при введении дополнительных ограничений, типа ограничения максимального количества битов.

Comment: Да, я вот то же подумал, что если бит не много можно просто найти количество бит в заранее заготовленной таблице

Answer (score 17):

Да не вопрос.

```
unsigned int count = 0;
for (; n; n >>= 1)
    count += n & 1;
```

Всего не более `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(n)` итераций, то есть, ограничено константой.

---

Вот ещё вам классический Кернигановский способ:

```
unsigned int count = 0;
for (; n; count++)
    n &= (n - 1); // убираем младший бит
```

Ограничение сверху то же, но на практике работает быстрее, т. к. использует одну итерацию на единичный бит.

---

Подборка различных способов подсчёта битов есть [тут](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive).

---

Обратите внимание, что хитрые компиляторы знают Кернигановский метод, и (на некоторых платформах и уровнях оптимизации) сокращают код, выбрасывая циклы, [до одной инструкции `popcnt`](https://godbolt.org/z/WPbron).

Comment: Возразить нечего. С такой точки зрения все реализации алгоритмов работают за O(1), ибо ограничены сверху некотрой константой от количества битов в storage.

Comment: @AnT: Ну, не все, т. к. может быть бесконечный цикл :) Но если количество итераций заранее ограничено заранее известной константой, это O(1) даже на бесконечной машине Тьюринга. Я вроде не пользуюсь конечностью памяти компьютера (а только фиксированностью длины целочисленных типов в каждой отдельной реализации компилятора C++ [при фиксированных ключах компиляции]).

Comment: @AnT: Строго говоря, об O-нотации можно говорить лишь если у нас есть ряд значений параметра алгоритма, расходящийся к бесконечности.

Comment: Я понимаю. Но, например, когда кто-то ищет *полиномальный* алгоритм для тестирования числа на простоту, то советовать ему простую brute-force проверку делителей до корня из `N` со словами "Братуха, я не то, что полиномиальный, я даже *константный* способ знаю!" обычно бесполезно - не поймут.

Comment: @AnT: Ну, здесь обычно _неявно_ подразумевается, что _длина_ числа возрастает к бесконечности, и ищется асимптотика в этих предположениях. А так, радужные таблицы появились не случайно, да.

Comment: Об о O-нотации можно говорить, когда мы говорим именно об *алгоритмах*, а не о конкретных *реализациях* этих алгороимов (занося разве что реализации для Машины Тьюринга в исключение из этого правила).

Comment: @AnT: Ну, если вы под _реализацией_ понимаете реализацию на физическом компьютере, то вы по большей части правы (хотя если алгоритм потоковый и результаты не расходятся, он вполне может принимать и как угодно длинный вход).

Comment: Выходит что msvc не такой уж и хитрый :(

Comment: @Джонни: да, эту оптимизацию msvc не знает. Впрочем, предыдущий метод не распознают и другие компиляторы, и компилируют в цикл.

Comment: `for (; n; n <<= 1)` - ошибка. надо `for (; n; n >>= 1)`

Comment: @AlexGlebe: Точно, вы правы, спасибо! Исправлю ответ.

Answer (score 8):

Создайте lookup-таблицу для 8-битных байтов (и/или 16-битных слов) и затем примените ее для подсчета битов в типе любого размера. Пока размер рассматриваемых типов константен, время подсчета тоже является константным.

Является ли такой подход (как, впрочем, и любой другой) O(1) - это уже у вас надо спрашивать.

P.S. Я обычно не мелочусь и сразу забабахиваю таблицу для 32-битных слов. Солидная таблица для солидных господ.

Comment: А вы уверены, что несколько гигабайт оперативной памяти нормально под такую таблицу?

Comment: @pavel: Если эффективность этой операции — единственное требование к коду, то почему бы и нет? Хотя да, кэш процессора и фсё такоэ, имеет смысл попрофилировать.

Comment: @pavel http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635794/195342

Comment: @VladD http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635794/195342

Answer (score 8):

Ну, я, как обычно, не могу без экспериментов :)
Итак, варианты -

```
// Hackers' Delight
int popHD(unsigned int x)
{
    x = x - ((x>>1) & 0x55555555);
    x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >>2) & 0x33333333);
    x = (x + (x>>4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
    x = x + (x >> 8);
    x = x + (x >> 16);
    return x & 0x3F;
}

int popLong(unsigned int x)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(x)
    {
        if (x&0x1) ++n;
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return n;
}

int popKern(unsigned int x)
{
    int n = 0;
    for (; x; n++)
        x &= (x - 1); // убираем младший бит
    return n;
}

int pop8(unsigned int x)
{
    static int count8[] =
    {
        // Из-за размера таблица удалена
    };
    return count8[x&0xFF] + count8[(x >> 8)&0xFF]
        + count8[(x >> 16)&0xFF] + count8[(x >> 24)&0xFF];
}

int pop16(unsigned int x)
{
    static int count16[] =
    {
        // Из-за размера таблица удалена
    };
    return count16[x&0xFFFF]+count16[(x>>16)&0xFFFF];
}

__popcnt(unsigned int) // MS VC++ specific
```

Если кому хочется посмотреть весь код - нет вопросов: http://vpaste.net/fD5DV

Далее набиваю вектор из 100000000 значений:

```
const int Count = 100000000;
vector<unsigned int> v;
v.reserve(Count);
for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
    v.push_back(dis(eng));
```

Ну, а все тесты имеют один вид:

```
{
    int count = 0;
    muTimer mu;  // Мой таймер
    for(unsigned int x: v) count += __popcnt(x);
    cout << count << "\n";
}
```

Для кэширования один проход делаю без засекания времени.

Вот как выглядят результаты на моей машине:

```
popHD    popLong    popKern     pop8      pop16     __popcnt
------------------------------------------------------------
89 ms    2514 ms    1505 ms    215 ms    200 ms       83 ms
88 ms    2525 ms    1482 ms    210 ms    195 ms       82 ms
```

Понятно, что от раза к разу пляшет, но несильно - для того и показываю два результата.

Выводы делайте сами :) Чистое суммирование

```
{
    int count = 0;
    muTimer mu;  // Мой таймер
    for(unsigned int x: v) count += x;
    cout << count << "\n";
}
```

дает примерно 25-27 ms.

**Update**
Посмотрел ассемблер. `popHD` сразу по 4 числа работает, с `xmm` регистрами, так что не знаю даже, радоваться или огорчаться :) Для отдельного значения `__popcnt`, понятно, быстрее...

Comment: HD вариант приближается к встроенному, но всё равно чуть медленее

Comment: @pavel Да вот сам удивлен... Думал, он должен давать скорость быстрее в разы. А даже если учесть время суммирования и цикла - не получается.

Comment: кто он? HD или встроенный?)

Comment: Ещё имеет смысл попробовать ассемблерную инструкцию `POPCNT`, а то intrinsic (по крайней мере в gcc) производит более сложный код.

Comment: @pavel Встроенный. Он вроде как разворачивается в соответствующую команду `popcnt ecx, DWORD PTR [eax]`

Comment: @VladD Отнюдь - http://vpaste.net/rvFeg

Comment: @pavel См. update в ответе...

Comment: @VladD Это не `popcnt` тормозит, это `popHD` использует `xmm`-регистры.

Comment: @Harry: В GCC получаем https://godbolt.org/g/DNSOhk, а исходник `__popcountdi2`, видимо, такой: https://github.com/01org/linux-sgx/blob/master/sdk/compiler-rt/popcountdi2.c (нашёл только версию для LLVM).

Comment: @Harry,  напишите сразу в ответе, какой компьютер (CPU)?

Comment: @avp Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30 GHz --- Windows 7 x64 --- Visual Studio 2015, компиляция x86

Comment: @Harry а можно полный пример? А то по ссылке обрелось что-то

Comment: @pavel Слишком большое :) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4DL1cHu0gJjOFhtc2NiUXhBVzA/view  и  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4DL1cHu0gJjOHZtaHZqWnZSZHc/view

Comment: @Harry ничего себе... g++ i7-7600 Win10 (16 GB оперативка) и  `1599981214
336141 mks
1599981214
2191796 mks
1599981214
1632803 mks
1599981214
146723 mks
1599981214
123125 mks
1599981214
298256 mks
-1686070202
41382 mks`

Comment: и для сравнения в дебаге. `1599981214
1510473 mks
1599981214
20191186 mks
1599981214
5490925 mks
1599981214
1262069 mks
1599981214
1294712 mks
1599981214
1209491 mks
-1686070202
862372 mks`

Comment: @pavel Как там у Стругацких - "служит неиссякаемым источником размышлений"... :)

Comment: @Harry просто у меня оптимальным оказался pop16. Видимо кеш процессора большой, всё влезло.

Comment: @VladD, посмотрел disasm в gdb для gcc `__popcountdi2`  в Ubuntu -- тот же код, что вы нашли для LLVM (c (x & 0x5555555555555555) + ((x >>  1) & 0x5555555555555555))

Answer (score 6):

Или же можно просто пользоваться стандартной библиотекой:

```cpp
#include <iostream> //std::cout
#include <bitset>   //std::bitset
#include <limits>   //std::numeric_limits

int main() {
    std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<int>::digits> bitset(7);
    std::cout << "7 has " << bitset.count() << " ones." << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

В gсс/g++ можете воспользоваться [встроенной функцией](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)

> Built-in Function: int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)
>
> ```
> Returns the number of 1-bits in x.
> ```

(хотя, конечно, скорость ее работы по сравнению с предложенными табличными алгоритмами, неизвестна).

P.S.

для X86 в gcc (g++) семейство функций `__builtin_popcount` было реализовано на основе таблицы из 256 элементов (на март 2017 посмотрел disasm  в gdb и увидел реализацию как в `int pop(unsigned long long x)` в ответе @Harry (c 0x5555555555555555 и т.д.));

по крайней мере в clang и icc эта функция (__builtin_popcount) называется так же, а в MSVC ее зовут [__popcnt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231(v=vs.100).aspx);

Comment: Должно быть эффективно, по крайней мере если компилировать не под generic-архитектуру: в современных интеловских процессорах есть для этого отдельная инструкция.

Comment: @VladD,  наверное, когда-нибудь будет. Пока gcc/g++ генерит `call __popcountdi2`

Comment: Хех: http://0x80.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html, ну и так оптимизирует ICC: https://godbolt.org/g/OK2lU5.

Comment: Хронометраж встроенной - см. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635794/195342

Comment: [clang, icc инструкцию popcnt генерируют, если target указать](https://godbolt.org/g/IGI1wl)

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например, для 64-битового `unsigned long long`:

```
int pop(unsigned long long x)
{
    x = (x & 0x5555555555555555) + ((x >>  1) & 0x5555555555555555);
    x = (x & 0x3333333333333333) + ((x >>  2) & 0x3333333333333333);
    x = (x & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) + ((x >>  4) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F);
    x = (x & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) + ((x >>  8) & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF);
    x = (x & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) + ((x >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF);
    x = (x & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) + ((x >> 32) & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF);
    return x & 0x0000000000007F;
}
```

Или вариант для 32-битного:

```
int pop(unsigned long long x)
{
    x = (x & 0x55555555) + ((x >>  1) & 0x55555555);
    x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >>  2) & 0x33333333);
    x = (x & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((x >>  4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);
    x = (x & 0x00FF00FF) + ((x >>  8) & 0x00FF00FF);
    x = (x & 0x0000FFFF) + ((x >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF);
    return x & 0x3F;
}
```

Он же, слегка переделанный:

```
int pop(unsigned long x)
{
    x = x - ((x>>1) & 0x55555555);
    x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >>2) & 0x33333333);
    x = (x + (x>>4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
    x = x + (x >> 8);
    x = x + (x >> 16);
    return x & 0x3F;
}
```

Comment: Этот вопрос точно отличается от http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/635594/181472? Если один и тот же ответ подходит к обоим, то это очень похоже на дубль.

Comment: Так ведь и вопрос является дублем. Если это вас раздражает - без проблем, я удалил тот ответ.

Comment: Не раздражает, просто пришла автоматическая тревога. :) Задубликатил вопросы.

Comment: @Harry, можете разъяснить как работает эта "магия"?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Кратко — число делится на группы по 2 бита, подсчитывается количество в каждой двухбитной группе и получается новое число. (0x555 = 01010101...). Потом группы по 2 собираются в группы по 4 , потом по 8 и т.д. Более подробно см. в книжке http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1838-3.html

Answer (score 4):

В C++20:

**[`#include <bit>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit)**

**[`std::popcount(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount)**

Answer (score 2):

Лень формулировать это на крестах, да и главное - идея. Идея такая: делаем в памяти массив длиной 65536 байт, значениями элементов которого являются количества единиц для соответствующего 16-битного целого. Потом обрабатываем ваше число фрагментами по два байта и суммируем количества единиц.

Comment: А зачем останавливаться? Сделайте lookup-таблицу длиной `MAXINT - MININT`, результат за одну выборку из неё.

Comment: Такая таблица не закэшируется.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что означает «не закэшируется», но вопрос, и что из этого?

Comment: Таблица размером 4 гигабайта не поместится в кэш, а таблица размером 64K поместится. Хотя, по условию задачи простой сдвиг через флаг переноса и сложение с коррекцией на asm и так будет за O(1).

Comment: Ну и что, что она не поместится в кэш процессора? Это не отменяет сам принцип.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Для 8 и 16 битных данных сдвиг в цикле займет разное время, следовательно это нельзя назвать O(1). А выборка из таблицы проходит за одинаковое время, главное что бы памяти хватило :)

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int count = 0;
for (; n; n >>= 1)
    count += n & 1;
```

или

```
unsigned int count = 0;
for (; n; n <<= 1)
    count += n & (0x80 << (sizeof(n)*8-8));
```

или

```
unsigned int count = 0;
for (; n; n <<= 1)
    count += av_get_cpu_flags() & FLAG_OVERFLOW;
count += av_get_cpu_flags() & FLAG_OVERFLOW;
```

Comment: Первый способ уже [предложен в ответе VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635556). Второй способ [работает неверно](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc61b72ffcfa858f). Третий способ использует  нестандартную функцию, и не помешало бы добавить пояснений, что это за функция.