# Посчитать количество единиц в двоичном представлении числа

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть набор целых положительных последовательных чисел от 0..N.

Нужно за O(N) посчитать количество единиц каждого числа в двоичном представлении и занести эту инфу в массив!

Возможно вопрос не имеет смысла,  но можно это как нибудь быстро сделать, вместо того чтобы высчитывать к-во единиц каждого числа за логарифм и получить N log 14 (14 потому что числа не превышают 10^4), надо это сделать просто за N.

Comment: А ничего, что O(N*log 14) — это в точности то же самое, что и O(N)?

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим начало таблицы количеств бит:

```
Число   Бит
0  0000 0

1  0001 1

2  0010 1
3  0011 2

4  0100 1
5  0101 2
6  0110 2
7  0111 3
```

Можно заметить, что каждую степень 2 добавляется один старший бит, а остальные идут так же, как во всей предыдущей таблице. Значит мы можем строить таблицу на основе ее самой, правильно выбрав смещение предыдущего элемента таблицы из которого взять количество. Когда N является степенью 2 (N & (N-1) равен нулю) надо начинать опять с начала таблицы.

```
int BITS[1024];
int main(){
 int N,offs;
 BITS[0]=0;
 for(N=1;N<1024;N++) {
   if(! (N & (N-1)) ) offs=N;
   BITS[N]=BITS[N-offs]+1;
 }
}
```