# Подсчитать количество единичек в двоичной форме числа

Tags: c++

Задание такое:

> задаётся число в десятичной форме, нужно подсчитать количество единичек в его двоичной.(число 13 - 3 единички, 12 - 2 единички)

Написала небольшой такой код, с нечетными подсчитывает правильно, с четными всегда ноль. В чем проблема, не подскажете?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a, b, c, i;

  cin >> a;
  c = a;
  i = 0;

  while(c > 1){
       b = a % 2;
       c = c / 2;

       if(b == 1){
          i = i + 1;
       }         
  }
  cout << i;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну что ж вы все время смотрите, есть ли единичка в `a`, а уменьшаете `c`? :)

Comment: Спасибо, сама бы не заметила)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/466515/3380

Answer (score 4):

В C++20 для этого есть стандартная функция:

```
#include <bit>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << std::popcount(a) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: На https://en.cppreference.com/ пока нет...

Comment: @Harry [Есть](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount), там и нашел. :)

Comment: Гм, а в поиске - не показывает...

Answer (score 3):

Ну что ж вы все время смотрите, есть ли единичка в `a`, а уменьшаете `c`? :)

А вообще - замените весь ваш цикл `while` вот этим:

```
for(;c; c >>= 1) i += c&1;
```

И еще - лучше использовать не `int`, а `unsigned int`.

А вообще этот вопрос очень детально разобран [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/635549/195342) - не пожалейте времени, посмотрите...

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int a;

  cin >> a;

  int i = 0;

  while(a >= 1){

       if(a % 2 == 1){

          i = i + 1;

       }    

       a = a / 2;     
  }

  cout << i;

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Гениально сменено шило на мыло :) Ошибку сами найдете или подсказать?

Comment: @Harry ээх а я думал вы не заметите.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]